# Como puedo heredar correctamente en java script?

Tags: javascript, herencia, prototipos

Tengo un problema con este ejercicio; no sé si esta es la forma correcta de heredar de un objeto que está heredando de otro objeto. La consola simplemente no me dice cuál es el error, pero cuando elimino el archivo de backend.js el programmer.js hereda de job correctamente.

Que hago?

Estuve investigando un poco pero no encuentro algo especifico

```
index.js
import Backend from "./Backend";

const jose = new Backend({
    name: 'Jose',
    lastName: 'morales',
    age: '21',
    gender: 'masculino',
    experience: '1 año',
    yearsWork: '0 años',
    title: 'none',
    tools: ['jS', 'webpack', 'css', 'sass'],
    asigServer: 1,
    asigLeguage: 2,
    asigBaseData: 2,
    asigProject: 2,
});

console.log(jose);
```

siempre que borro este archivo backend.js y modifico en index.js la instancia de new a "const jose = new Programmer({})" el programa funciona correctamente...

```
Backend.js
import Programmer from './Programmer';

function Backend({
    name,
    lastName,
    age,
    gender,
    experience,
    yearsWork,
    title,
    tools = [],
    asigServer,
    asigLeguage,
    asigBaseData,
    asigProject,
}){
    
    Programmer.call(
        this,
        name,
        lastName,
        age,
        gender,
        experience,
        yearsWork,
        title,
        tools,
    ); 
    this.asigServer = asigServer;
    this.asigLeguage = asigLeguage;
    this.asigBaseData = asigBaseData;
    this.asigProject = asigProject;
}

Backend.prototype = new Programmer;
Backend.prototype.constructor = Backend;  

export default Backend;
```

```
Programmer.js
import Job from "./Job";

function Programmer({
    name,
    lastName,
    age,
    gender, 
    experience,
    yearsWork,
    title,
    tools = [],
}){
    Job.call(this,name,lastName,age,gender);
    this.experience = experience;
    this.yearsWork = yearsWork;
    this.title = title;
    this.tools = tools;
    //Methods
    this.programar = () => {
        console.log(`${this.title}`);
    };
}


Programmer.prototype = new Job;
Programmer.prototype.constructor = Programmer;

export default Programmer;
```

```
Job.js
function Job(
    name,
    lastName,
    age,
    gender
){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    //Methods
    this.getName = () =>{
        console.log(`${this.name}`)
    }
    this.setName = (name) =>{
        this.name = name;
        console.log(`${this.name}`)
    }
}

export default Job;
```

Comment: Para heredar de una clase puedes usar la palabra ``extends``. Ejemplo:
``class MyFecha extends Date{}``  , similar a lo que se hace en Java. 
``var fecha = new MyFecha();``

Comment: Ocurre que es una tarea y necesito hacerlo sin el uso de class :(